# laravel testing (phpunit) post request with param

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

My testing class:

```
class QuarterlyReportFormController extends Controller
{
    //protected $baseUrl = 'http://pp.loc'; //the same as APP_URL from .env.testing 

    public function uu(Request $request, QuarterlyReportForm $quarterlyReportForm)
    {
        dd($quarterlyReportForm->id);        
    }
}
```

in routes/web.php

```
 Route::post('/aa/{quarterlyReportForm}/uu', 'QuarterlyReportFormController@uu');
```

My test function:

```
public function testUu()
{
    $obj = (new QuarterlyReportForm)->create([
        'user_id' => $this->createUser(),
        'complete'=> 0,
        'active' => 1    
    ]);
    $this->assertNotEmpty($obj->id);
    $this->assertEquals(1, $obj->id);
    
    $responseUU = $this->post( "/aa/{$obj->id}/uu", ['complete' => 1]);  
    dd($responseUU);  //this is return null
}
```

Why this line:
dd($responseUU);
return null when i executing test it is ./vendor/bin/phpunit?

When I execute my function in Firefox it is return some value (not null).

Comment: Is your $baseUrl correctly set in TestCase.php?

Comment: I add   
         dd(config('app.url'));
in 'uu' method and I receive APP_URL from .env.testing file (when I execute testing)

Comment: Okay, but what it you run `dd($this->baseUrl);` - is it the same?

Comment: I receive the following error:
[2021-12-23 10:17:53] testing.ERROR: Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\QuarterlyReportFormController::$baseUrl {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined property: App\\Http\\Controllers\\QuarterlyReportFormController::$baseUrl at /var/www/pzzj/app/Http/Controllers/QuarterlyReportFormController.php:276)"
I try add:
protected $baseUrl = 'http://pp.loc';    
in TestCase and I receive the same error.

Comment: But it seems like you did the dd() inside the controller. You should do it inside the test. What happens then?

Comment: I add dd('_________'.$quarterlyReportForm->id.'++++++++'); inside 'uu' method and after run the test I reveive: "_________++++++++". The test not pass to the line dd($responseUU); in the test (so my post is a little bit confusing).